# Windows 10 Microsoft Family account for Child gone missing / unable to use outlook.com

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls

I have created 2 child accounts on a Windows 10 laptop a month ago. It seems like a really cool feature that I can get weekly updates on what's going on.

The weekly update used to give me the name of the child. But recently, the e-mail title is simply "Weekly activity report for (empty)".

In addition, another Child's account, which has never logged in, has gone completely missing from the laptop.

From the Windows 10 laptop, I do not see accounts under "Your Family". Instead, one of my child is showing under "Other users".

From my account online, I see 2 child accounts under "Your family". But there are no names. It only says "After signs in to a Windows Phone or Windows 10 device, it'll show up here.". I can only remove them and not edit.

I've picked @outlook.com e-mail for each of them. I've tried signing in to outlook.com using their account and password and I got some strange error. It appears as if their account do not exist because I cannot reset password. But clearly their e-mail addresses are taken.

I seem to recall that when I first created the account, I saw something like "ask an adult for permission" in the child's account. I thought it is related to cloud services and I didn't proceed. Not sure if it has anything to do with the problem I experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you're supposed to click on the ACCEPT button from the email, since you didn't then I think you have blocked them. Try [Verify your Outlook.com account](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows/outlook/verify-account)

If you can access the emails then remove the accounts from your computer and add them again, then go in to the emails and ACCEPT the family request.

Good Luck, let me now f this helps

Comment: I guess I am screwed as when I added their accounts, they have no e-mail addresses. So I created outlook.com e-mail along the process. Now their e-mail are also inaccessible. I cannot reset password because outlook say there is no such account but in fact their IDs are used (by me).